# Python code for converting table in hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

SELECT TRANSFORM on the customer table by creating a new table. Your new target table should have only three columns, `c_custkey` (no changes), `c_address`, and `c_city`.

For the `c_address` column, shorten it to 5 characters.

For `c_city`, add a space and a `#` to indicate the digit at the end                                         (e.g., `UNITED KI2` => `UNITED KI #2`, or `INDONESIA4` => `INDONESIA #4`).

```
create table customer (
  c_custkey     int,
  c_name        varchar(25),
  c_address     varchar(25),
  c_city        varchar(10),
  c_nation      varchar(15),
  c_region      varchar(12),
  c_phone       varchar(15),
  c_mktsegment  varchar(10)    
);
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

create table customer_ty (
  c_custkey     int,
  c_address     STRING,
  c_city        STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE

;
```

## customer table data

```
1|Customer#000000001|j5JsirBM9P|MOROCCO  0|MOROCCO|AFRICA|25-989-741-2988|BUILDING|
2|Customer#000000002|487LW1dovn6Q4dMVym|JORDAN   1|JORDAN|MIDDLE EAST|23-768-687-3665|AUTOMOBILE|
3|Customer#000000003|fkRGN8n|ARGENTINA7|ARGENTINA|AMERICA|11-719-748-3364|AUTOMOBILE|
4|Customer#000000004|4u58h f|EGYPT    4|EGYPT|MIDDLE EAST|14-128-190-5944|MACHINERY|
5|Customer#000000005|hwBtxkoBF qSW4KrI|CANADA   5|CANADA|AMERICA|13-750-942-6364|HOUSEHOLD|
6|Customer#000000006| g1s,pzDenUEBW3O,2 pxu|SAUDI ARA2|SAUDI ARABIA|MIDDLE EAST|30-114-968-4951|AUTOMOBILE|
7|Customer#000000007|8OkMVLQ1dK6Mbu6WG9|CHINA    0|CHINA|ASIA|28-190-982-9759|AUTOMOBILE|
8|Customer#000000008|j,pZ,Qp,qtFEo0r0c 92qo|PERU     6|PERU|AMERICA|27-147-574-9335|BUILDING|
9|Customer#000000009|vgIql8H6zoyuLMFN|INDIA    6|INDIA|ASIA|18-338-906-3675|FURNITURE|
10|Customer#000000010|Vf mQ6Ug9Ucf5OKGYq fs|ETHIOPIA 9|ETHIOPIA|AFRICA|15-741-346-9870|HOUSEHOLD|
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question so that the code is easy to see, and so we can help you better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`c_city` transformation can be easily done using regexp, see example for Hive:

```
select regexp_replace('INDONESIA4', '(.*?)(\\d+)$','$1 #$2');
```

Result

```
INDONESIA #4
```

And it is not clear how the address should be shortened. Please clarify the rules, me or someone else may help w this also.